# Avro: detect union field types in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, avro

Given the following schema that contains a union of three types:

```
{
    "namespace":"com.example",
    "type":"record",
    "name":"TestObject",

    "fields":[

        {
            "name":"element",
            "type": [
                "null",
                "string",
                {
                "name":"element_type",
                "type": "enum",
                "symbols": ["TYPE1", "TYPE2"]
                }
            ],
            "default":"TYPE1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to detect the schema of an element when using Python?

The following code loads the data as a dictionary, making it impossible to detect the actual type of the "element" field:

```
reader = DataFileReader(open("generic.avro", "rb"), DatumReader())
for entry in reader:
    print(entry)
reader.close()
```

Thanks!